# ExoPlayer: How to seek into just one of currently playing tracks?

Tags: android, exoplayer

I have an ExoPlayer instance initialized with 4 tracks. 2 of them are MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer instances, each with its own ExtractorSampleSource.

I'd like to start the playback of one of those track from the middle.

I'm waiting until I get the MSG_PLAYER_STATE_READY message to be able to get the duration of the tracks and then calling seektoUs on the sample-source (also tried calling seekTo on the renderer), but both give unpredictable results.

What's the proper way to seek into a single track while the rest of the tracks play from the beginning?

Comment: Dude where you learnt how to use exo player can u give me a link the documentation is so vague

Comment: @prathamkesarkar Started out with the demo player and mostly by reading the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve the issue by overriding my custom TrackRenderer's doSomeWork method and calling super.doSomeWork with a custom positionUs based on the logic I needed.